# huffman algorithm needs help in storing char code

Tags: c, network-programming

I have written program to obtain the code for each char as shown in the program output.

enter some text: nslfaslfjasfj
text = "nslfaslfjasfj"

a:2

f:3

j:2

l:2

n:1

s:3

Huffman Algorithm
Below is "CHAR CODE":

n code:111

j code:110

f code:10

s code:01

l code:001

a code:000

My next step should be storing the above in structure and comparing it my original text = "nslfaslfjasfj" to encode as "11101.....so on".

I am finding a problem in storing "CHAR CODE" in structure. Should it be stored as string like string s="111" and then stored in the strucuture?.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the input will try writing bits and then store it.. I will try and let you know the result.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the point of Huffman encoding is to decrease the length of the message, i.e. compress it. This means you want to be writing bits out, not the characters '0' and '1'. Therefore it makes sense to store your character codes also as bits, and use bit operations to transfer them to the stream. Storing a pair (character code, code length) for each element is sufficient to construct the encoding.

Having said that, you can do it with strings as you suggest. It's not wrong, and it might make it a little easier to debug, but it will perform worse.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to make some kind of "BitWriter". We covered the topic of bitwise I/O in Java for huffman coding in a data structures class at my university, the [lecture slides are freely available here](http://ieng6.ucsd.edu/~cs100f/Lectures/lec4/lec4.pdf). Obviously Java != C, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're trying to *compress* something, using strings would be a horrible idea. You'll want to store the char codes as raw binary.

Comment: But strings are an excellent method to use while developing the algorithm.  Once the algorithm works correctly, bits should be used and the results output in a binary {ASCII} string.